# MVC 6 WebFarm: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm running MVC 6 (vNext) in a webfarm scenario (ARR front-end with multiple AppServers).  Server affinity is off.

When I bounce between app servers from one request to another I get the error

> CryptographicException: The key {3275ccad-973d-43ca-930f-fbac4d276640} was not found in the key ring.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.

Previously, I believe this was handled by setting a static MachineKey in the web.config.

As I understand it, we've now moved to a new DataProtection API and I've tried the following, thinking the application name is used as some kind of seed:

```
        services.AddDataProtection();
        services.ConfigureDataProtection(configure =>
        {                
            configure.SetApplicationName("WebAppName");
        });
```

which does not work to solve the problem.

Any idea how to solve this issue in vNext?

Comment: In addition to accepted answer, it's now very easy to persist data protection keys on Redis which works well on a Web Farm scenario. See http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-core-authentication-in-a-load-balanced-environment-with-haproxy-and-redis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Explanation

You'll need to reuse the same key.

If you are on Azure, the keys are synced by NAS-type storage on `%HOME%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys`.

For locally run application, they are stored in the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys` of the user running the application or stored in the registry if it's being executed in IIS.

If none of the above match, the key is generated for the lifetime of the process.

### Solution

So the first option is not available (Azure only). However, you could sync the keys from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys` of the user running your application on each machine running your application.

But even better, you could just point it to a network share like this:

```cs
sc.ConfigureDataProtection(configure =>
{
    // persist keys to a specific directory
    configure.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"Z:\temp-keys\"));
});
```

This will allow you to scale while keeping your security.

**Important:** Your keys will expire every 90 days. It will be important to regenerate them frequently.

You can change it using this bit of code but the shorter, the safer you are.

```cs
services.ConfigureDataProtection(configure =>
{
    // use 14-day lifetime instead of 90-day lifetime
    configure.SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
});
```

### Source

- [Key Encryption at Rest](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest.html)
- [Default Settings](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings.html)

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  This is an on-premise (non-azure) deployment.  So, with this option, are we then saying that the app can't run unless the network share is online?  

Seems like a brittle linchpin, compared to machineconfig keys, no?

Comment: Yes and no. If the app is frequently accessed, the keys are generated 2 days ahead of time and once they are read, all operations are from in-memory. They will cache those key in-memory until they need to update them again.

Comment: Thanks!  So there is now no other mechanism for sharing keys across machines beyond network share?

Comment: Yes there is but you're now closer to the core. There's an [`IXmlRepository`](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection/Repositories/IXmlRepository.cs) interface that exist to change the storage. There is 3 built-in: [file](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection/Repositories/FileSystemXmlRepository.cs), registry, in-memory. You could reimplement your own and define it in the `ConfigureServices` section.

Comment: I will note that it seems to be possible to abuse the API by calling "PersistKeysToFileSystem" and specifying a local path and running it in my test environment to generate a keyfile.  If I then copy that keyfile to all the machines in the webfarm (at the same relative path), it seems to work also.  Clearly this won't work with rotating out old keys, but with sufficiently long expiration times that part of it is not an issue.  Of course, that all seems to bypass many of the benefits the API offers, but I thought I'd mention it anyway for sake of discussion.

Comment: @MaximeRouiller if you store via Azure blob storage, and upload pre existing data protection keys, these will be used instead of generating new ones?