# CryptographicException when publishing same Asp.Net Core to multiple nodes

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-traffic-manager

When I publish the same app to multiple nodes in Azure and use traffic manager to route the requests evenly, I get the following error in ApplicationInsights and I'm unable to determine the cause:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)","outerId":"11388138","message":"The key {XXXXXXXXXXXXXX} was not found in the key ring.","type":"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException","id":"9351281"}]
```

We have never seen this error before adding the new node.

Your assistance is appreciated.

Update: I have disabled traffic manager and linked dns to 2 different webapps, the error is still there, perhaps deploying the same solution to two different webapps causes the issue?

Comment: You're using anti forgery tokens, they're encrypted or have a signature and the required key isn't available on the new box. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319802/mvc-6-webfarm-the-antiforgery-token-could-not-be-decrypted) might help or point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Matt Thank you so much, can you kindly help us on how to achieve a solution in Azure for the problem? I think that the other answer is a non-azure case.

Comment: @Matt would enabling ARR Affinity in both solve the problem?

Comment: The first part of the linked answer talks about Azure keys, but sorry I haven't had to deal with this on Azure. Some more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers) that might help, good luck!

Comment: @Matt thanks a lot, please see edit above